# Trigger did not run?

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger *"after insert/update/delete/"*. It is supposed to count Balance on Account table based on transactions in Transaction table. It is on Transaction table. I am getting Balance discrepancies rarely, so have decided to add some logging into it. It dumps inserted+deleted tables (they are combined into a table var) and *tsql* statement which fired it. Judging from my log, it looks like the *trigger* did not fire for some inserts into Transaction table. Can this happen ? Are there any TSQL statement which change table data without firing trigger (except truncate table etc)?

Here is the *trigger* :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_AccountBalance]
ON [dbo].[tbl_GLTransaction] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

set nocount on
begin try
    declare @OldOptions int = @@OPTIONS

    set xact_abort off

    declare @IsDebug bit = 1

    declare @CurrentDateTime datetime = getutcdate()
    declare @TriggerMessage varchar(max), @TriggerId int

    if @IsDebug = 1
    begin

        select @TriggerId = isnull(max(TriggerId), 0) + 1
        from uManageDBLogs.dbo.tbl_TriggerLog

        declare @dbcc_INPUTBUFFER table(EventType nvarchar(30), Parameters Int, EventInfo nvarchar(4000) )  

        declare @my_spid varchar(20) = CAST(@@SPID as varchar(20)) 

        insert @dbcc_INPUTBUFFER  
        exec('DBCC INPUTBUFFER ('+@my_spid+')')

        select @TriggerMessage = replace(EventInfo, '''', '''''') from @dbcc_INPUTBUFFER

        insert into uManageDBLogs.dbo.tbl_TriggerLog (TriggerId, "Message", CreateDate)
        values (@TriggerId, @TriggerMessage, @CurrentDateTime)
    end

    declare @Oper int
    select @Oper = 0 

    -- determine type of sql statement
    if exists (select * from inserted) select @Oper = @Oper + 1
    if exists (select * from deleted) select @Oper = @Oper + 2

    if @IsDebug = 1
    begin
        select @TriggerMessage = '@Oper = ' + convert(varchar, @Oper)

        insert into uManageDBLogs.dbo.tbl_TriggerLog (TriggerId, "Message", CreateDate)
        values (@TriggerId, @TriggerMessage, @CurrentDateTime)
    end

    if @Oper = 0 return -- No data changed

    declare @TomorrowDate date = dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, getdate()))
    declare @CurrentDate date = convert(date, getdate())

    -- transactions from both inserted and deleted tables
    declare @tbl_Trans table (FirmId int, GLAccountId int, 
        AmountDebit money, AmountCredit money, "Status" char(1), TableType char(1))

    declare @tbl_AccountCounters table (FirmId int, GLAccountId int, Balance money) 
    declare @IsChange bit = null

    insert into @tbl_Trans (FirmId, GLAccountId, AmountDebit, AmountCredit, "Status", TableType)
        select FirmId, GLAccountId, AmountDebit, AmountCredit, "Status", 'I'
        from inserted
        union
        select FirmId, GLAccountId, AmountDebit, AmountCredit, "Status", 'D'
        from deleted

        if @IsDebug = 1
        begin
            select @TriggerMessage = (select * from @tbl_Trans for xml path ('tbl_Trans'))

            insert into uManageDBLogs.dbo.tbl_TriggerLog (TriggerId, "Message", CreateDate)
            values (@TriggerId, @TriggerMessage, @CurrentDateTime)
        end

        insert into @tbl_AccountCounters (FirmId, GLAccountId, Balance)
            select FirmId, GLAccountId, 0
            from @tbl_Trans
            group by FirmId, GLAccountId

        if @Oper = 1 or @Oper = 2 -- insert/delete
        begin
            update @tbl_AccountCounters
            set Balance = cnt.TransSum
            from @tbl_AccountCounters as ac join
            (
                select trans.FirmId, trans.GLAccountId, 
                    isnull(sum((trans.AmountDebit - trans.AmountCredit) * iif(trans.TableType = 'I', 1, -1)), 0)  as TransSum
                from @tbl_Trans as trans
                where trans.Status = 'A'
                group by trans.FirmId, trans.GLAccountId
            ) as cnt on ac.FirmId = cnt.FirmId and ac.GLAccountId = cnt.GLAccountId

            select @IsChange = 1
        end
        else
        begin
            if update(AmountDebit) or update(AmountCredit) or update(Status) or update(GLAccountId)
            begin
                update @tbl_AccountCounters
                set Balance = cnt.TransBalance
                from @tbl_AccountCounters as ac join
                    (select trans.FirmId, trans.GLAccountId, isnull(sum(trans.AmountDebit - trans.AmountCredit), 0) as TransBalance
                    from dbo.tbl_GLTransaction as trans
                    where trans."Status" = 'A' and exists (select 1 from @tbl_AccountCounters as ac 
                        where ac.GLAccountId = trans.GLAccountId and ac.FirmId = trans.FirmId)
                    group by trans.FirmId, trans.GLAccountId) as cnt on 
                        ac.FirmId = cnt.FirmId and ac.GLAccountId = cnt.GLAccountId

                select @IsChange = 0
            end
        end

        if @IsDebug = 1
        begin
            select @TriggerMessage = '@IsChange = ' + isnull(convert(varchar, @IsChange), 'null')

            insert into uManageDBLogs.dbo.tbl_TriggerLog (TriggerId, "Message", CreateDate)
            values (@TriggerId, @TriggerMessage, @CurrentDateTime)

            select @TriggerMessage = (select * from @tbl_AccountCounters for xml path ('tbl_AccountCounters'))

            insert into uManageDBLogs.dbo.tbl_TriggerLog (TriggerId, "Message", CreateDate)
            values (@TriggerId, @TriggerMessage, @CurrentDateTime)
        end

        if @IsChange is not null
        begin
            update tbl_GLAccount
            set tbl_GLAccount.Balance = iif(@IsChange = 1, cnt.Balance + acc.Balance, cnt.Balance),
                tbl_GLAccount.LastUpdate = getutcdate(),
                tbl_GLAccount.LastUpdatedBy = 1 
            from @tbl_AccountCounters as cnt join dbo.tbl_GLAccount as acc on
                cnt.FirmId = acc.FirmId and cnt.GLAccountId = acc.GLAccountId
        end
        if (16384 & @OldOptions) = 16384 set xact_abort on
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @ErrorLine varchar(max)
        select @ErrorLine = uManageDb.dbo.udf_GetErrorInfo()

        insert into uManageDb.dbo.tbl_TriggerError ("Name", "Message", CreateDate) 
        values ('AccountingDB..trg_AccountBalance', @ErrorLine, GETUTCDATE())
    end catch
```

Comment: I don't think _'here is some of the code'_ or _'judging from my log that I haven't shown'_ give readers much useful to work with. The alternative seems to be for readers to wade through unfamiliar code and guess why you use the conditions you use. What is not being inserted to your log that you expect to be there? Why should that be inserted, given the conditionals you've coded in your trigger? What are the conditions for?

Comment: I just did not want to junk this place with my long code. First statements write to log (@IsDebug = 1) sql query which started trigger. I have 5 trigger runs in my log adding 6 transactions, but the Transaction table has 14 ones. Somehow there are no records in log for them (atleast that sql query). I'll put all the trigger text now :)

Comment: set xact_abort = off is a try to skip errors.

Comment: For any columns that the trigger references, you should post examples of the input data that it did not catch as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it. I have this line:

```
select .. from inserted 
union 
select .. from deleted
```

and they inserted 5 trans for $300 and 4 trans $100. I've got 2 records (300 and 100) in my @tbl_Trans (it was in the log). That's probably was the bug. So log hellps and trigger run as it had to.

I'll replace union with union all.

Comment: I've got a new version of the trigger which has no:        "if Oper = 1 or Oper = 2 -- insert/delete" and counts only Balance difference. I might start to glitch soon to. So I might have to ask you again soon :)